# How to NPM publish so that consumers can imports from different top-level directories

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-publish, npm-pack

I am publishing a library to NPM. The library was written in Typescript, and the result of the Typescript compilation is put in a `lib/` folder.  The main file is an `index.ts` that exports my public API:

```js
export * from './functions';
export * from './models';
```

In package.json, I specify:

```
{"main": "lib/index.js", "types": "lib/index.d.ts", "files": ["lib/**/*"]}
```

Once my package is published and installed elsewhere, its folder structure is:

```
lib/
  index.js
  index.d.ts
  functions/
    index.ts
    my-function.ts
  models/
    index.ts
    my-model.ts
```

the consumer imports everything from the package root:

```js
import {someFunction, SomeModel} from 'a-library';
```

This works, but I like the idea of segregating paths. One path for functions, and another for models.  Currently if I remove the top-level index, the imports become segregated but they now include the `lib/` folder in the path which I don't want:

```js
import {someFunction} from 'a-library/lib/functions';
import {SomeModel} from 'a-library/lib/models';
```

What I would actually like to accomplish is the same but without `lib/`.  I have a working solution but it seems too convoluted.  Here is what works:

1. In package.json, remove the `main` `types` and `files` key.
2. Delete or empty the `index.ts`
3. To publish replace the simple `npm publish` with the following steps:

   - copy package.json and paste it into `/lib` folder
   - cd into the `/lib` folder and run `npm pack` and take note of the created tarball's name
   - run `npm publish {{TARBALL_NAME}}`
   - cd back up to the project root

As a result, the published package has the following folder structure once installed:

```
functions/
  index.ts
  my-function.ts
models/
  index.ts
  my-model.ts
```

Because things are no longer nested within a `lib/` directory the consumer can import as I wished:

```js
import {someFunction} from 'a-library/functions';
import {SomeModel} from 'a-library/models';
```

The problem is that packing and publishing to accomplish this seems too cumbersome. I'll never get my teammates to by into a 3 or 4 step process when they've just been running `npm publish` all this time.

Is there a simpler way to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: You could potentially move the 4 steps to a npm script to automate it, and your teammates can run the script, like `npm run pack-publish`

Comment: did you find a solution to this?